# Extracting hidden representations from an autoencoder using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

After having trained an AutoEncoder with PyTorch, how can I extract the low-dimensional embeddings of input features at some hidden-level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define your model such that it optionally returns the intermediate pytorch variable calculated during the forward pass. Simple example:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(hidden_size, 3)) #reduce the size

    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(3, hidden_size),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(hidden_size, input_size),
    nn.ReLU()) #reduce the size

def forward(self, x, return_encoding = False):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)

    if return_encoding:
        return decoded,encoded
    return decoded
```

Comment: That's great, sorry I'm pretty new to PyTorch, hence trying to wrap my hands around it. Many thanks :) Did you miss another nn.ReLU() in the encoder after the final linear layer?

Comment: Sounds good. If this works go ahead and accept the answer to help keep SO organized, thanks!

Comment: accepted! Can you just precise me if you forgot an extra nn.ReLU() in the encoder or you just didn't put it?

Comment: I just copied this network architecture from your other question. It's likely that you'd want an activation function after the final fully connected layer in the encoder

Comment: got it, so I guess I had forgotten to put a final activation function in the encoder part..Many thanks!!